# Preserving data type while concatenating DataFrames with nullable integers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, missing-data

How can one preserve data type while concatenating DataFrames with nullable integers?

```py
# input data
import pandas as pd
t1 = pd.DataFrame(index=[0], data={'x':[1]}, dtype='UInt8')
t2 = pd.DataFrame(index=[1], data={'y':[1]}, dtype='UInt8')

'''actual result'''
print(t1.dtypes)
# x    UInt8
# dtype: object
print(t2.dtypes)
# y    UInt8
# dtype: object
print(pd.concat([t1,t2], join='outer', sort=False).dtypes)
# x    object
# y    object
# dtype: object
```

Why are data types of the concatenation result changed to `object` and how can one make sure that the data types are preserved during concatenation? I.e. I want data types of `x` and `y` to remain `UInt8` after concatenation:

```py
'''expected result'''
print(pd.concat([t1,t2], join='outer', sort=False).dtypes)
# x    UInt8
# y    UInt8
# dtype: object
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: according to the printed output, looks like y and y still are UInt8

Comment: @Will Are you reading the actual or the expected output?

Comment: It looks to me that they are being reported as being `object` before the concatenation.

Comment: @Acccumulation If you experiment with commands like `t1 = pd.DataFrame(index=[0], data={'x':[1]}, dtype='uint8')`, you will see that the type provided is shown next to the line starting with `x`, and so this is the one specifying the type of `x`. I am not sure what is the meaning of `dtype: object` since it is always the same in any DataFrame I have seen. Let us set `t3 = pd.concat([t1,t2], join='outer', sort=False)`, then `type(t3.at[0,'x'])` is `<class 'int'>` while `type(t3.at[1,'x'])` is `<class 'float'>` and so `t3` has elements of different types and that is why the data type is `object`

Comment: Explicit conversion (i.e. `pd.concat([t1,t2], join='outer', sort=False).astype('UInt8').dtypes)` does give correct data types. However, on this route, one has to do explicit conversion for each data type of the input DataFrames.